# How do I get Livewallpaper on HTC Wildfire?

Tags: htc-wildfire, live-wallpaper

I have a HTC Wildfire , and i have updated my android from 2.1 to 2.2 as i was developing application which creates the livewallpaper.

Now the problem is inside my application there a option to launch Livewallpaper chooser , but when i try to lunch it its giving me following error while testing on actual device.

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.service.wallpaper.LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER }
```

apart from this since i have updated to android 2.2 i haven't seen the livewallpaper option in my HTC wildfire phone.

There is only "HTC Wallpaper" and "Gallery" Option under "Select wallpaper from".

so i don't know if there isn't any livewallper in HTC wildfire then how to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have too a HTC wildfire. For the live wallpaper, you can't use the HTC sense launcher. You must use another launcher like ADW or launcherpro.

When you use another launcher, a new option "live wallpaper" will appear.

Comment: so if i will download the launcherpro or ADW then will my htc sense launcher would get replaced ?

Comment: No, the htc sense won't be replaced. Both launcher will be installed and android will ask you each time you press the home button witch launcher use. (You will also have the possibility to remember this choice)

Comment: okay great , so according to you which one is better (launcherpro or ADW) in terms of user experience (with live wallpaper) ?

Comment: In term of live wallpaper experience, the two are the same ... For a more general use, I prefer LauncherPro. But you install the two and test yourself witch one you prefer.

Comment: Well i have downloaded launchpro but there is no livewallpaper selection in it there is only Wallpapers under Add to Home Screen and after clicking on Wallpapers i can see three options in "Select Wallpaper From" i.e.
Gallery , HTC Wallpapers and Wallpaper Gallery

Comment: Strange, works for me ... Have you a live wallpaper installed ? I things that the wildfire doesn't come with default live wallpaper installed.

Comment: well i have installed a livewallpaper via eclipse but stills its not giving me an option to select "livewallpaper"

Comment: i tried n download livewallpaper from anroid market but when i tried to open the livewallpaper its show me "Unsupported handset" error

Comment: @Hunt Get a wallpaper that supports your device.  Developers can target specific handsets.

Comment: Well i got the link which says HTC Wildfire doesn't support livewallpaper

http://www.livewallpapers.org/support/